# Expand paths from a channel

Tags: nextflow

My data is structured as samples that are run in batches. So I have a directory hierarchy like this:

```
/path/to/dir/batch_1/sample_1
/path/to/dir/batch_1/sample_2
/path/to/dir/batch_1/...
/path/to/dir/batch_2/sample_1
/path/to/dir/batch_2/sample_2
/path/to/dir/batch_2/...
/path/to/dir/...
```

I want to apply a process to every sample *for a given subset of batches*. One approach that works is to generate a channel listing the samples:

```java
path_to_samples= Channel
    .fromPath(['/path/to/dir/batch_2/sample_*',
               '/path/to/dir/batch_322/sample_*'], type: 'dir' )

process my_process{

    input:
    path(sample) from path_to_samples

    """
    do stuff
    """
}
```

Now, I'd like to provide the batch names separately, and have the script find the corresponding samples. Something like that:

```java
params.root_dir = '/path/to/dir/'
params.batch_names = Channel.from('batch_2', 'batch_322')

// make samples channel: incorrect
path_to_samples = params.batch_names
                        .map { params.root_dir + it + 'sample_*' }
                        .toPath()

process my_process{

    input:
    path(sample) from path_to_samples

    """
    do stuff
    """
}
```

So, I am thinking incorrectly about channels? Is there a way to "flatten" the sample list through channel operations? Or is the correct approach to make a more complex Groovy closure that will list the files in each batch directory and return it as a tuple or list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how you'd like to provide your input batch names, but you could create your list of glob patterns using a simple closure then use them to create your input channel:

```
params.root_dir = '/path/to/dir'
params.batch_names = /path/to/batch_names.txt'

batch_names = file(params.batch_names)
sample_dirs = batch_names.readLines().collect { "${params.root_dir}/${it}/sample_*" }

samples = Channel.fromPath( sample_dirs, type: 'dir' )

process my_process{

    input:
    path(sample) from samples

    """
    ls -l "${sample}"
    """
}
```

I would be inclined to just leave the input glob pattern as a param, though. This approach offers the most flexibility, but may not suit your use case:

```
params.samples = '/path/to/dir/batch_{2,322}/sample_*'

samples = Channel.fromPath( params.samples, type: 'dir' )
```

Comment: Thank you! I dislike the solution with a glob in my case as the `root_dir` is a long path full of random strings, and the batch names themselves are actually random strings; so that doesn't seem suited for a user input.